# SASS 3.4.21 and map import

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have issue with import of any SASS maps (that i haven't created)

The setup:

- Sass -v > Sass 3.4.21
- Compass --pre > 1.1.0.alpha.3
- Sass extension is .scss

---

e.g. installing [sass-font-stacker](https://github.com/synapticism/sass-font-stacker) results to:

..error style.scss (Line 11 of index.scss: Invalid CSS after " baskerville": expected ")", was ": (Baskerv...")

---

Any idea?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you're compiling with Compass 1.0 or later?  If you have another dependency, it might be specifying an older version.

Comment: yep... 

Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris)
Copyright (c) 2008-2016 Chris Eppstein
Released under the MIT License.
Compass is charityware.

Comment: Keep in mind that `compass -v` will only display the newest version you have installed.  You'll need to check your [full gem listing](http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-basics/#listing-installed-gems) to see which versions you have installed.  Try eliminating the old ones to be sure.  If you're not using Compass directly via command line, double check to make sure whatever application is doing the compiling (eg. Koala, Scout) is configured to use the latest version.

Comment: Thx, here's the list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.6)
chunky_png (1.3.5)
compass (1.0.3)
compass-core (1.0.3)
compass-import-once (1.0.5)
ffi (1.9.10 x64-mingw32)
io-console (0.4.3)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (5.4.3)
multi_json (1.11.2)
power_assert (0.2.2)
psych (2.0.8)
rake (10.4.2)
rb-fsevent (0.9.7)
rb-inotify (0.9.5)
rdoc (4.2.0)
rubygems-update (2.5.1)
sass (3.4.21)
test-unit (3.0.8)

i'm also using the newest Koala where in the settings  i have "use the system compass compiler" checked

Comment: i'm going on with command line and the other maps i tried to import works. ( i tried more, some has issues anyway :-/ )
but overall solved...